# Get all href tags and links from a list using BeautifulSoup + Python

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I was able to get a list of webpage elements with the tag `div` and its contents. It contains a list of all available links in a specific `div`.

The list looks like this:

```
# I formatted the list contents to look like an HTML code

classroom_links = 
[<div class="main_class">
    <div class="sub_class">
        <a href="link1" id="id_name"></a>
        <a href="link2" id="id_name"></a>
        <a href="link3" id="id_name"></a>
        <a href="link4" id="id_name"></a>
        <a href="link5" id="id_name"></a>
    </div>
</div>
]

classroomLinks = soup.find_all("div", {"class": "main_class"})
for links in classroomLinks:
    print(links.find('a')['href'])
```

Output:

```
`"link1"`
```

But this prints only the first link. I am unable to print all the remaining links.

Comment: You need to iterate over `<a>` tags inside the `link` loop.

Comment: @AlexandreB. Could you elaborate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to iterate over `a` tags for each element of the list:

```
for dom in classroom_links:
    for aTag in dom.find_all("a"):
        print(aTag)
```

Full example:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
classroom_links = [BeautifulSoup("""<div class="main_class">
    <div class="sub_class">
        <a href="link1" id="id_name"></a>
        <a href="link2" id="id_name"></a>
        <a href="link3" id="id_name"></a>
        <a href="link4" id="id_name"></a>
        <a href="link5" id="id_name"></a>
    </div>
</div>""")]


for dom in classroom_links:
    for aTag in dom.find_all("a"):
        print(aTag)
# <a href="link1" id="id_name"></a>
# <a href="link2" id="id_name"></a>
# <a href="link3" id="id_name"></a>
# <a href="link4" id="id_name"></a>
# <a href="link5" id="id_name"></a>
```